# Compile php 5.5 with pdo_mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-extension, nmake

I have tried to build php with those settings:

```
    configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-cgi --with-mysql --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql=shared
```

and always return me that error if I try to compile with --with-pdo-mysql

```
    Creating library Release_TS\php_pdo_mysql.lib and object Release_TS\php_pdo_mysql.exp
    mysql_driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___mysqlnd_init referenced in function _mysql_handle_autocommit
    mysql_driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mysqlnd_connect referenced in function _mysql_handle_autocommit
    mysql_driver.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mysqlnd_get_client_info referenced in function _mysql_handle_autocommit
    pdo_mysql.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__mysqlnd_get_client_info
    mysql_statement.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___mysqlnd_fetch_lengths referenced in function _pdo_mysql_stmt_execute_prepared_mysqlnd
    mysql_statement.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mysqlnd_allocator referenced in function _PDO_DBG_ENTER
    pdo_mysql.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__mysqlnd_reverse_api_register_api referenced in function _get_module
    Release_TS\php_pdo_mysql.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
```

if i try without --with-pdo-mysql I can compile without errors.
I use Visual Studio 2013

EDIT: resolved just by adding

```
--with-extra-libs=deps\lib --with-extra-includes=deps\include
```

Comment: On a side note, have you viewed viewed `phpinfo();` at all? According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php): _"PDO ships with PHP 5.1, and is available as a PECL extension for PHP 5.0; PDO requires the new OO features in the core of PHP 5, and so will not run with earlier versions of PHP."_ It appears you don't need to compile with PDO as it's already included.

Comment: @War10ck Sorry for this but it's first time I try to compile php. Tnks for the answer.